# Update only part of the word embedding matrix in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, word-embedding

Assuming that I want to update a pre-trained word-embedding matrix during training, is there a way to update only a subset of the word embedding matrix?

I have looked into the Tensorflow API page and found this:

```py
# Create an optimizer.
opt = GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1)

# Compute the gradients for a list of variables.
grads_and_vars = opt.compute_gradients(loss, <list of variables>)

# grads_and_vars is a list of tuples (gradient, variable).  Do whatever you
# need to the 'gradient' part, for example cap them, etc.
capped_grads_and_vars = [(MyCapper(gv[0]), gv[1])) for gv in grads_and_vars]

# Ask the optimizer to apply the capped gradients.
opt.apply_gradients(capped_grads_and_vars)
```

However how do I apply that to the word-embedding matrix. Suppose I do:

```py
word_emb = tf.Variable(0.2 * tf.random_uniform([syn0.shape[0],s['es']], minval=-1.0, maxval=1.0, dtype=tf.float32),name='word_emb',trainable=False)

gather_emb = tf.gather(word_emb,indices) #assuming that I pass some indices as placeholder through feed_dict

opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4)
grad = opt.compute_gradients(loss,gather_emb)
```

How do I then use `opt.apply_gradients` and `tf.scatter_update` to update the original embeddign matrix? (Also, tensorflow throws an error if the second argument of `compute_gradient` is not a `tf.Variable`)

Comment: How do you define "subset" here?

Comment: Only a subset of rows in the embedding matrix. Since each row is a word-embedding vector, it is just a subset of word-embedding vectors from the original word embedding matrix

Comment: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/faq_tutorial.html
This is what I would like to achieve but in Tensorflow

Answer (score 22):

**TL;DR:** The default implementation of [`opt.minimize(loss)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/train.html#Optimizer.minimize), TensorFlow will generate a *sparse* update for `word_emb` that modifies only the rows of `word_emb` that participated in the forward pass.

The gradient of the [`tf.gather(word_emb, indices)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#gather) op with respect to `word_emb` is a [`tf.IndexedSlices`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#IndexedSlices) object ([see the implementation for more details](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c1a40c7b9085719cb120ae92f991f86d0757af7e/tensorflow/python/ops/array_grad.py#L176)). This object represents a sparse tensor that is zero everywhere, except for the rows selected by `indices`. A call to `opt.minimize(loss)` calls [`AdamOptimizer._apply_sparse(word_emb_grad, word_emb)`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c1a40c7b9085719cb120ae92f991f86d0757af7e/tensorflow/python/training/adam.py#L131), which makes a call to `tf.scatter_sub(word_emb, ...)`* that updates only the rows of `word_emb` that were selected by `indices`.

If on the other hand you want to modify the `tf.IndexedSlices` that is returned by [`opt.compute_gradients(loss, word_emb)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/train.html#Optimizer.compute_gradients), you can perform arbitrary TensorFlow operations on its `indices` and `values` properties, and create a new `tf.IndexedSlices` that can be passed to [`opt.apply_gradients([(word_emb, ...)])`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/train.html#Optimizer.apply_gradients). For example, you could cap the gradients using `MyCapper()` (as in the example) using the following calls:

```
grad, = opt.compute_gradients(loss, word_emb)
train_op = opt.apply_gradients(
    [tf.IndexedSlices(MyCapper(grad.values), grad.indices)])
```

Similarly, you could change the set of indices that will be modified by creating a new `tf.IndexedSlices` with a different indices.

---

* In general, if you want to update only part of a variable in TensorFlow, you can use the [`tf.scatter_update()`, `tf.scatter_add()`, or `tf.scatter_sub()` operators](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#sparse-variable-updates), which respectively set, add to (`+=`) or subtract from (`-=`) the value previously stored in a variable.

Comment: are you sure this works as advertised? See my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35828037/training-a-cnn-with-pre-trained-word-embeddings-is-very-slow-tensorflow) and the links therein. It seems that for some reason TensorFlow is converting the IndexedSlices into a dense tensor and the updates slow down.

Comment: It certainly works if your embedding variable is the direct `params` argument to `tf.gather()` (or `tf.nn.embedding_lookup()`). The `IndexedSlices` is converted to a dense tensor if the gradient backpropagates through any more ops that don't have gradient functions specialized for handling `IndexedSlices` (at present I believe only `tf.concat()` has such a specialization).

Comment: Wondering if this can be used to update specific word vectors only as in the case I've got pre-trained vectors for most of my words but a few are new and are in need of training.

Comment: tf.scatter_sub op seems don't have gradient function specialized for handling IndexedSlices. I ask a question about it, and I think you may know about it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59763351/how-to-compute-gradients-with-tf-scatter-sub

Answer (score 7):

Since you just want to select the elements to be updated (and not to change the gradients), you can do as follows.

Let `indices_to_update` be a boolean tensor that indicates the indices you wish to update, and `entry_stop_gradients` is defined in the link, Then:

```
gather_emb = entry_stop_gradients(gather_emb, indices_to_update)
```

([Source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9162))

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I was also struggling with such a problem. In my case, I needed to train a model with w2v embeddings, but not all of the tokens existed in embedding matrix. Thus for those tokens which were not in matrix, I made random initialization. Of course tokens for which embeddings were already trained, shouldn't be updated, thus I've came up with such a solution:

```
class PartialEmbeddingsUpdate(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
def __init__(self, len_vocab, 
             weights,
            indices_to_update):
    super(PartialEmbeddingsUpdate, self).__init__()
    self.embeddings = tf.Variable(weights, name='embedding', dtype=tf.float32)
    self.bool_mask = tf.equal(tf.expand_dims(tf.range(0,len_vocab),1), tf.expand_dims(indices_to_update,0))
    self.bool_mask = tf.reduce_any(self.bool_mask,1)
    self.bool_mask_not = tf.logical_not(self.bool_mask)
    self.bool_mask_not = tf.expand_dims(tf.cast(self.bool_mask_not, dtype=self.embeddings.dtype),1)
    self.bool_mask = tf.expand_dims(tf.cast(self.bool_mask, dtype=self.embeddings.dtype),1)
    
def call(self, input):
    input = tf.cast(input, dtype=tf.int32)
    embeddings = tf.stop_gradient(self.bool_mask_not * self.embeddings) + self.bool_mask * self.embeddings
    return tf.gather(embeddings,input)
```

Where len_vocab - is your vocabulary length, weights - matrix of weights (some of which shouldn't be updated) and indices_to_update - indices of those tokens which should be updated. After that I applied this layer instead of tf.keras.layers.Embeddings. Hope it helps everyone, who encountered the same problem.