# Large word embedding matrix update in tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, nlp, deep-learning, word-embedding

Recently I am using a CNN to do text classification which is described in http://www.wildml.com/2015/12/implementing-a-cnn-for-text-classification-in-tensorflow/.

My dataset is quite large and the vocabulary size is more than 1M words. My training algorithm becomes much slower when the vocabulary size gets bigger. There is a warning message saying that  "....tensorflow/python/ops/gradients.py:87: UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor with 145017088 elements. This may consume a large amount of memory."

I am thinking this may be caused by a dense gradient update on the embedding matrix. Does anyone have any ideas on that? There is a post [Update only part of the word embedding matrix in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35803425/update-only-part-of-the-word-embedding-matrix-in-tensorflow) discussing similar issue. The top answer states that tensorflow only updates specific rows. Why did it change in my case?

Thanks!