# make part of word embedding trainable

Tags: tensorflow, word-embedding

Is there anyway to update only a small subset of pretrained glove word embeddings in `TensorFlow`. I am looking for pointers on how to implement such case in `TensorFlow`.

The reason I want only a few words' embedding to be updated is that I am doing a question answering task and is using pretrained glove embeddings. But I would like to make words in the query that indicate high level query type to be trainable and get updated in the training process, words such as 'what', 'when', 'where', 'who' etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update only part of the word embedding matrix in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35803425/update-only-part-of-the-word-embedding-matrix-in-tensorflow)

Comment: I did see that question. However with the selected answer it was still unclear to me how exactly this should be done.