# Tensorflow - Train only a subset of embedding matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have an embedding matrix `e` defined as follows

```
e = tf.get_variable(name="embedding", shape=[n_e, d], 
              initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=False))
```

where `n_e` refers to the number of entities and `d` is the number of latent dimensions. For this example, say d=10.

Training:

```
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss)
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, global_step=global_step)
```

The model is saved after training. 
At some point later, new entities(e.g., 2) are added resulting in `n_e_new`. Now I would like to re-train the model, however retaining the embeddings for the already trained entities i.e., retraining only the delta (the 2 new entities).

I load the saved `e` and

```
init_e = np.zeros((n_e_new, d), dtype=np.float32)
r = list(range(n_e_new - 2))
init_e[r, :] = # load e from saved model

e = tf.get_variable(name="embedding", initializer=init_e)
gather_e = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(e, [n_e, n_e+1])
```

Training:

```
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss, gather_e)
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, global_step=global_step)
```

I get an error at `compute_gradients`: 
**NotImplementedError: ('Trying to optimize unsupported type ', )**

I understand that the second parameter `gather_e` to `compute_gradients` is not a variable but cannot figure out how to achieve this partial training/update.

P.S - I also had a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35803425/update-only-part-of-the-word-embedding-matrix-in-tensorflow), but cannot seem to find a solution there either.

**EDIT:**
Code sample(as per the approach suggested by @meruf):

```
if new_data_available:
    e = tf.get_variable(name="embedding", shape=[n_e_new, 1, d],
              initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=False))
    e_old = tf.get_variable(name="embedding_old", initializer=<load e from saved model>, trainable=False)
    e_new = tf.concat([e_old, e], 0)

else:
    e = tf.get_variable(name="embedding", shape=[n_e, d], 
              initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=False))
```

Lookup is as follows:

```
if new_data_available:
    var_p = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(e_new, indices)
else:
    var_p = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(e, indices)

loss = #some operations on var_p and other variabes that are a result of the lookup above
```

The issue is that when `new_data_available` is true, neither `e` nor `e_new` change during each epoch. They remain same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35803425/update-only-part-of-the-word-embedding-matrix-in-tensorflow

Answer (score 1):

You should not change code at optimizer level. You can easily tell tensorflow which variable is trainable or not.

Let's take a look at `tf.getVariable()` defination,

```
tf.get_variable(
name,
shape=None,
dtype=None,
initializer=None,
regularizer=None,
trainable=True,
collections=None,
caching_device=None,
partitioner=None,
validate_shape=True,
use_resource=None,
custom_getter=None,
constraint=None
)
```

Here `trainable` parameter represents that if the parameter is trainable or not. When you do not want to train a parameter then make it false.

for your case make 2 set of variable. One is `trainable=True` and for other `trainable=false`.

Assume you have 100 pretrained variable and 10 new variables to train. Now load the pretrained variable to `A` and new variables to `B`.

**Note:**
For implementation details, you should take a look at [`tf.cond`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) function for runtime decisions. Mostly for lookup. because now your new `B` embeddings have index starting from `0`. But you may have assigned them from `# of pretrained embedding+1` in your dataset or program. So in tensorflow you can take runtime decision that

pseudocode

```
if index_number is >= number of pretrained embedding
    index_number = index_number - number of pretrained embedding
    look_up on B matrix
else
    look_up on A matrix
```

---

[An Ipython Notebook of the example. (slightly different than the example given here.)](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18HnIP0kmtCQhG1C7w8j-KRryP79x18KX)

update:

Let's take look at an example what I meant,

## at first load the library

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

### declare the placeholders

```
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
z = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, []) # is the example in the x contains new data or not
```

### create the network

```
e = tf.get_variable(name="embedding", shape=[5,10],initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=False))
e_old = tf.get_variable(name="embedding1", shape=[5,10],initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=False),trainable=False)
out = tf.cond(z,lambda : e, lambda : e_old)
lookup = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(out,x)
W = tf.get_variable(name="weight", shape=[10,2],initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=False))
l = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(lookup,W))
y = tf.nn.softmax(l)
```

### calculate loss

```
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
```

### optimize loss

```
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)
```

### load and run the graph

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
```

### print the initialized value

We are printing the values so that we can check later if our value changes or not.

```
e_out_tf,e_out_old_tf = sess.run([e,e_old])



print("New Data ", e_out_tf)
print("Old Data", e_out_old_tf)




 ('New Data ', array([[-0.38952214, -0.37217963,  0.11370762, -0.13024905,  0.11420489,
            -0.09138191,  0.13781562, -0.1624797 , -0.27410012, -0.5404499 ],
           [-0.0065698 ,  0.04728106,  0.53637034, -0.13864517, -0.36171854,
             0.40325132,  0.7172644 , -0.28067762, -0.0258827 , -0.5615116 ],
           [-0.17240004,  0.3765518 ,  0.4658525 ,  0.16545495, -0.37515178,
            -0.39557686, -0.50662124, -0.06570222, -0.3605038 ,  0.13746035],
           [ 0.19647208, -0.16588202,  0.5739292 ,  0.43803877, -0.05350745,
             0.71350956,  0.39937392, -0.45939735,  0.09050641, -0.18077391],
           [-0.05588558,  0.7295865 ,  0.42288807,  0.57227516,  0.7268311 ,
            -0.1194113 ,  0.28589466,  0.09422033, -0.10094754,  0.3942643 ]],
          dtype=float32))
    ('Old Data', array([[ 0.5308224 , -0.14003026, -0.7685277 ,  0.06644323, -0.02585996,
            -0.1713268 ,  0.04987739,  0.01220775,  0.33571896,  0.19891626],
           [ 0.3288728 , -0.09298109,  0.14795913,  0.21343362,  0.14123142,
            -0.19770677,  0.7366793 ,  0.38711038,  0.37526497,  0.440099  ],
           [-0.29200613,  0.4852043 ,  0.55407804, -0.13675605, -0.2815263 ,
            -0.00703347,  0.31396288, -0.7152872 ,  0.0844975 ,  0.4210107 ],
           [ 0.5046112 ,  0.3085646 ,  0.19497707, -0.5193338 , -0.0429871 ,
            -0.5231836 , -0.38976955, -0.2300536 , -0.00906788, -0.1689194 ],
           [-0.1231837 ,  0.54029703,  0.45702592, -0.07886257, -0.6420077 ,
            -0.24090563, -0.02165782, -0.44103763, -0.20914222,  0.40911582]],
          dtype=float32))
```

## test case

Now we will test our theory if 
1. non-trainable variable changes or not
2. trainable variable changes or not.
We declared an additional placeholder `z` to indicate if the our input ontains `new data` or `old data`.

Here, **index 0** contains **new data** that is trainable if `z` is `True`.

```
feed_dict={x: [0],z:True}
lookup_tf = sess.run([lookup], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

### check that the value matches with above value.

```
print(lookup_tf)


[array([[-0.38952214, -0.37217963,  0.11370762, -0.13024905,  0.11420489,
        -0.09138191,  0.13781562, -0.1624797 , -0.27410012, -0.5404499 ]],
      dtype=float32)]
```

### we will send z=True to indicate on which embedding you want to lookup.

So while you send a batch make sure that the batch contains only either old data or new data.

```
feed_dict={x: [0], y_: [[0,1]], z:True} 
_, = sess.run([train_step], feed_dict=feed_dict)


lookup_tf = sess.run([lookup], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

### after training let's check is it behaves ok or not.

```
print(lookup_tf)


[array([[-0.559212  , -0.362611  ,  0.06011545, -0.02056453,  0.26133284,
        -0.24933788,  0.18598196, -0.00602196, -0.12775017, -0.6666256 ]],
      dtype=float32)]
```

See **index 0** contains new data that is trainable and changes from previous value because of **SGD update**.

## let's try the opposite

```
feed_dict={x: [0], y_: [[0,1]], z:False} 
lookup_tf = sess.run([lookup], feed_dict=feed_dict)
print(lookup_tf)
_, = sess.run([train_step], feed_dict=feed_dict)
lookup_tf = sess.run([lookup], feed_dict=feed_dict)
print(lookup_tf)


[array([[ 0.5308224 , -0.14003026, -0.7685277 ,  0.06644323, -0.02585996,
        -0.1713268 ,  0.04987739,  0.01220775,  0.33571896,  0.19891626]],
      dtype=float32)]
[array([[ 0.5308224 , -0.14003026, -0.7685277 ,  0.06644323, -0.02585996,
        -0.1713268 ,  0.04987739,  0.01220775,  0.33571896,  0.19891626]],
      dtype=float32)]
```

Comment: I am aware of the `trainable` parameter of TensorFlow variables, but wanted to know if there was a way to have only one variable and make a part of it non-trainable. Since using pre-trained embeddings and retraining when new entities arrive is a common use-case, I thought there must be a generic approach to tackle this. 

I shall try your solution and see if it works for me. Thanks.

Comment: I tried using 2 different variables (A with trainable false and B with trainable true) and doing the lookup on a tensor C (A concatenated with B). And the loss if then computed based on C. However, the issue I am facing is that the variable B is never updated during the training. It stays the same. How can I solve this?

Comment: @meruf - Added code to the original post. Please help.

Comment: do not forget to check the notebook I shared.