# How to compute gradients with tf.scatter_sub?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, gradient

When implementing lambda-opt(an algorithm published on KDD'19) in tensorflow, I came across a problem to compute gradients with  **tf.scatter_sub**。

θ refers to an embedding matrix for docid.
The formulation is

θ(t+1)=θ(t) - α*(grad+2*λ*θ),

```
delta = theta_grad_no_reg.values * lr + 2 * lr * cur_scale * cur_theta
next_theta_tensor = tf.scatter_sub(theta,theta_grad_no_reg.indices,delta)
```

then I use θ(t+1) for some computation. Finally, I want to compute gradients with respect to λ, not θ.

But the gradient is None.

I wrote a demo like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

w = tf.constant([[1.0], [2.0], [3.0]], dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.constant([5.0], dtype=tf.float32)

# θ
emb_matrix = tf.get_variable("embedding_name", shape=(10, 3),
                    initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(),dtype=tf.float32)
# get one line emb
cur_emb=tf.nn.embedding_lookup(emb_matrix,[0])
# The λ matrix
doc_lambda = tf.get_variable(name='docid_lambda', shape=(10, 3),
                             initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(), dtype=tf.float32)
# get one line λ
cur_lambda=tf.nn.embedding_lookup(doc_lambda, [0])

# θ(t+1) Tensor("ScatterSub:0", shape=(10, 3), dtype=float32_ref)
next_emb_matrix=tf.scatter_sub(emb_matrix, [0], (cur_emb *cur_lambda)) 
# do some compute with θ(t+1) Tensor ,not Variable
next_cur_emb=tf.nn.embedding_lookup(next_emb_matrix,[0])

y_ = tf.matmul(next_cur_emb, w)
loss = tf.reduce_mean((y - y_) ** 2)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
grad_var_list=optimizer.compute_gradients(loss)
print(grad_var_list)
# [(None, <tf.Variable 'embedding_name:0' shape=(10, 3) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'docid_lambda:0' shape=(10, 3) dtype=float32_ref>)]
```

The gradient is None, too. It seems that **tf.scatter_sub** op doesn't provide gradient？

Thanks for your help！

If you have an interest in this algorithm, you can search for it, but it's not important about this question.

Comment: I am not familiar with `tf.scatter_sub` but I do know you can get gradients with `tf.GradientTape()`. You do something like `tape.gradients()` and you pass the loss and your train variables. But I am also not sure which tf version you are using.

Comment: This [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/autodiff) might be helpful.

Comment: Because I am working on the company’s original architecture, the tf version is 1.10. So I 
 can't use tf.GradientTape() in that it was introduced in 2.0. @Siddhant Tandon